# how to list this array in hbs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, handlebars.js

iam trying to list this ingredients Array

> > ingredients:Array in DB

```
ingredients:Array
0:"Tapioca / Kappa - 1 medium"
1:"Gram Flour / Kadala Mavu - 1 Cup"
2:"Rice Flour - 1/2 Cup"
3:"Turmeric Powder - 1 or 2 pinch"
4:"Chilly Powder - 1 Tspn"
```

etc..

here, I am trying to list the ingredients but not getting line by line how to solve this,

> > > recipe.hbs

```
<div class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h4>Ingredients</h4>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {{#each recipe}}
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="pre-line">{{ingredients}}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> > submit-recipe.hbs

```
<div class="col-12">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Ingredients</label><br>
      <small>Example: Ice</small>
      <div class="ingredientList">
        <div class="ingredeintDiv mb-1">
          <input type="text" name="ingredients" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

this is the submit form

- GET /recipe/:id
- Recipe

> > recipeController.js

```
     exports.exploreRecipe = async(req, res) => {
          try {
            let recipeId = req.params.id;
            const recipe = await Recipe.findById(recipeId);
            res.render('recipe', {recipe} );
          } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({message: error.message || "Error Occured" 
          });
          }
        }
```

> > recipe-Schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ingredients: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Breakfast', 'Snacks', 'variety_dish', 'Lunch'],
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
recipeSchema.index({ name: 'text', description: 'text' });
// WildCard Indexing
//recipeSchema.index({ "$**" : 'text' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('recipes', recipeSchema);
```

this is  recipeSchema model

Comment: Show how you pass the variable to the template please

Comment: ok, iam added my submit hbs form

Comment: There is usually some javascript code that passes variables to the template

Comment: yes javascript, here is that.

Comment: Client-side javascript has nothing to do with rendering the hbs template. This template is rendered before this javascript runs

Comment: ho , ok  here is that.

Comment: Are you sure that `recipe` is an array? The name suggest that it is an object.

Comment: Let's show schema model ,

Comment: ingredients is an array , recipe is an COLLECTION

Comment: sir, how to make, ingredients line by line ,

Comment: If `ingredients` is array, then you will need to `#each` over it in order to render each item it contains. If you wanted to join the elements, for example, with a `,` delimiter, you would need to create a helper to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `ingredients` is a property of `recipe` so you have to use `recipe.ingredients`. Also, `{{this}}` is used to display the item of the array.

```
<div class="row pt-4">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h4>Ingredients</h4>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" style="width: 287px;">
      {{#each recipe}}
        {{#each ingredients}}
          <li class="list-group-item" style="pre-line">{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir , now the ingredients not getting

Comment: Sadge, hope someone else would know how to fix it

Comment: Sorry for wasting your precious time because of me, iam sorry sir i can fix by styling but ,It is not a good way right?

Comment: @1435 What is not working for you with this solution?